# How to check if string includes substring with an unknown character in Python?

Tags: python, substring

Sorry if the title is undescriptive, I'm bad at summarizing.

I want to check if a string includes a substring with an unknown character.

For example, if I have a string like "foobar", I want to check if it has something like "oo?ar" or "ooba?", signifying that a character is there, just that it can be any character.

Comment: You need to read about regular expressions.  That's one answer.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall` returns a list of all matches of a regex (docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) pattern in a string. The regex character `.` matches any character, but not a newline.

```py
import re

txt = "foobar"

x = re.findall("oo.ar", txt) # -> ['oobar']
y = re.findall("ooba.", txt) # -> ['oobar']
print(x)
print(y)
```